# Disable recursive scraping within scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

I've been using scrapy to validate links on my site for several months, it works perfectly for crawling my entire site. Now I'm trying to update my script to disable recursion, I only want to scrape a specific set of URLs and so far I'm unsuccessful.

Here's the contents of **siteScrape.py**

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.http import HtmlResponse
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from my_scrape.items import MyScrapeItem

class MySpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'siteScrape'
    allowed_domains = ['www.example.com']
    start_urls = ['https://www.example.com/page']

    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(canonicalize=True, unique=True), callback='parse_item', follow=False),
        )

    def parse_item(self, response):
        for link in response.xpath("//a"):
            yield {
                'ANCHOR_TEXT': ','.join(link.xpath("text()").getall()),
                'TARGET_URL': ','.join(link.xpath("@href").getall()),
            }
```

And here's the relevant class within **pipelines.py**

```
class CsvPipeline(object):

    @classmethod
    def from_crawler(cls, crawler):
        return cls(crawler.settings)

    def __init__(self, settings):
        csvFile = settings['CSV_FILE']
        self.file = open(csvFile, 'wb')
        self.exporter = CsvItemExporter(self.file, str)
        self.exporter.start_exporting()

    def close_spider(self, spider):
        self.exporter.finish_exporting()
        self.file.close()

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        self.exporter.export_item(item)
        return item
```

The issue I'm having is that my page has 15 links, and this is scraping each of those as well (but not going any further than those). If I set `follow=True` it works perfectly for scraping an entire site recursively.

I tried updating this to use `Spider` instead of `CrawlSpider`, that runs without error but returns an empty CSV file. How can I update my recursive scraper to pull the contents of only the pages which are explicitly listed?

Answer (score 0):

I finally cracked this after some research with trial & error. What I learned is that scrapy by default does not follow links recursively, my original spider was set up specifically to do that. And the reason that `Spider` was returning 0 results was that I had not set it properly to return anything. So with a bit of experimentation I was able to get through this.

The issue was in my spider file. Here's the version of **siteScrape.py** that works for me.

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.http import HtmlResponse
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from my_scrape.items import MyScrapeItem

class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'siteScrape'
    allowed_domains = ['www.example.com']
    start_urls = ['https://www.example.com/page']

    def parse(self, response):
        for link in response.xpath("//a"):
            yield {
                'ANCHOR_TEXT': link.xpath("text()").get(),
                'TARGET_URL': link.xpath("@href").get(),
            }
```

This spider scrapes one page, `www.example.com/page`, and returns the anchor text & target URL for each link on the page. My pipelines didn't change at all, I'm able to send these results to a CSV file without issue.